# Como ativar a versão móvel de um website no Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css

No site que a minha equipa está a trabalhar (mundosemincendios.pt), a versão móvel do Google Chrome parece não ativar. Quando baixo o Firefox ou Opera para o meu telemóvel, o site ajusta-se ao telemóvel e fica direito.

Mas com a aplicação do Chrome para móvel, o site não se ajusta à resolução do ecrã.

O que fazer? Será que há algum código que ativa o ajuste? O site está online portanto podem pesquisar, e agradeço se conseguirem ajudar-me!

Comment: Podias disponibilizar prints para ver a diferença? É que abri em chrome e firefox no telemóvel e aparece da mesma forma

Comment: Amigo edite a sua pergunta e coloque o seu HTML inteiro e CSS. Só falando assim fica difícil te dar uma resposta precisa.

Comment: No topo do seu HTML dentro da tag `<head> </head>` coloque essa meta tag, as vezes pode resolver. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`